# Force Feeding Medicines To Kitten

Tags: cats, behavior

It is my first pet. Due to Diarrhea , vet has asked me to force feed the kitten 4 days. Before feeding, the behavior seems to be normal but after force feeding, the kitten's behavior seems like it just hates every one and becomes sad(whenever it is laying on the ground, I touch him and he leaves the place and finds another place where no one is around). Is it normal or am I being so harsh on this little buddy ?

Comment: Don't touch the kitten whenever it is laying on the ground. It possibly don't like it and it will get worse. Ignore it most of the time and try to have some positive experiences a day. Play with him or give him treats. And give him time. Much time. Trust always needs time.

Answer (score 2):

First, I think it would depend on how much you are force feeding your kitten, too much at one time could be giving him or her an upset tummy. If you are sure that you are not overfeeding, it is possible that the kitten is just tired of getting handled and would like to be left alone. I would also take into consideration that if you are having to force feed the kitten, then it stands to reason that they are already sick and not going to feel better just yet. I think that if you have reached a point where you are force feeding it, it just isn't going to feel well until it starts to heal. I wouldn't expect the kitten to show signs of happiness and wellness until it gets over whatever it has, sometimes, as with children, the cure hurts. Good Luck and I can assure you that you will see a change in behavior when the kitten starts to feel better.